# Activar un enlace usando Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Deseo que mi menú de navegación se active con un color definido según la navegación del usuario. Mi primer enlace lo tengo activado con un color establecido. Sin embargo, al cambiar de enlace no cambia de color como el enlace activado. Estoy utilizando la clase `.active` pero no realiza la activación. ¿Cómo podría modificarlo?

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo-nav.png" alt="Nav Logo">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="galeria.html">Galería</a>
                </li>
                
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-item a:hover {
    color: #FF4600;
}

.nav-item .nav-link.active {
    color: #FF4600;
}
```

Comment: 1) Probé tu código y funciona. 2) Te falta cerrar la etiqueta ul. 3) Lo más probable es que haya otra regla pisando a la que tu estas colocando, es style que tienes en tu pregunta agrégalo al final de todo

Comment: Agrega un [example]